# ftp filezilla server stops accepting connections after some time

Tags: windows, ftp

I'm encountering the following issue.

My filezilla FTP server stops after some time, the time is varying from 5 hours to 24 hours.

I raised the filezilla server log and the trace below were the only thing, I was able to see

```
(001170) 27/07/2018 05:45:23 - project_mgt (192.168.79.8)> STOR DC04-Project Indicators.xls
FileZilla Server 0.9.60 beta started
Initializing Server.
Creating listen socket on port 20...
Creating listen socket on port 21...
Creating listen socket on port 990...
Creating listen socket on port 990...
Failed to bind the listen socket on port 990 to the following IPs: ::0 0.0.0.0
Server online.
```

As you can see, it is not saying much.

I checked the event log and it is not saying much neither, as the only log happens at 03:27 as you can see and the ftp server stopped at 05:45Am.

I'm unsure what else should I check.

If you have ideas, they are welcomed.

Thank you.

Update 1

---

One of thing I've noticed is that when I'm trying to reach the FTP by a ftp client, I have this error

```
Status :    Connection to 192.168.79.2:21...
Status :    Connection failure with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by the server".
```

[image]

Update 2

---

After some checking, it seems that there is some issues with the number of connections allowed

[image]

Comment: Is anyone connecting at that time?

Comment: @Burgi we have multiple users who are connecting to the ftp sever, in an automatic manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much checking, one automate, that a colleague of mine developped, was over connecting through FTP.

The connection were not correctly closed, causing the FTP server to crash.